# how to change the tab color of a worksheet with Apache Poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to set the background color of a worksheet tab using Apache POI. I can't seem to figure out how to set the style on the tabs themselves though.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: See also [*Apache POI: Frequently Asked Questions*](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N100BA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that it is not possible. boo. This was the best explanation of why:

http://osdir.com/ml/user-poi.apache.org/2009-03/msg00034.html

Comment: Just for people in the future reading this. For XSSF sheets it's now possible to set tab color. The XSSFSheet.setTabColor method uses the indexed colors available in POI to set tab color.

Answer (score 8):

As commented by Alfabravo... it's possible now to change the `XSSFSheet` tab color.

```
sheet.setTabColor(int colorIndex)
```

is used for that, and so if we use

```
 sheet.setTabColor(num);
```

- `num = 0` : set Black Color in tab.
- `num = 1` : set White Color in tab.
- `num = 2` : set Red Color in tab.
- `num = 3` : set Green Color in tab.
- `num = 4` : set Blue Color in tab.
- `num = 5` : set Yellow Color in tab.

and so on.

Comment: List of colors: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/IndexedColors.html e.g. sheet.setTabColor(IndexedColor.BLACK.getIndex())

Answer (score 2):

As commented by Piotr,
to color tabs in POI 3.11 i had to use:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors;
sheet.setTabColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
```

(Note that it is "IndexedColor**s**", not "IndexedColor" like showed by Piotr.)
here is a list showing the colors: http://jlcon.iteye.com/blog/1122538

Comment: The method setTabColor(int colorIndex) is deprecated. One should use setTabColor(XSSFColor color).
`final XSSFSheet diffExpected = wbDiff.createSheet( refSheetName );  diffExpected.setTabColor( new XSSFColor( Color.RED ) );`