# Apcahe poi Update Hssf sheet tab color using Xssf

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have an xls file created by HSSF sheet and workbook. Now i want to change sheets tab color. I can see we can set tab color using Xssf sheet. But i am not able to edit HSSF sheet using XSSF. Even i am not able to change cell value also. I can not change whole code written in HSSF. So there is any way to do this.

I have tried below code to change tab color:

```
FileInputStreamfsIP= new FileInputStream("/data.xlsx");  
XSSFWorkbook wbx = new XSSFWorkbook(fsIP);
XSSFSheet worksheetx = wbx.getSheetAt(0); 

worksheetx.setTabColor(IndexedColors.BLUE.getIndex());

Cell cell = worksheetx.getRow(2).getCell(0);   
cell.setCellValue("OverRide existing value");

fsIP.close(); 
output_file =new FileOutputStream("/data.xlsx");  
wb.write(output_file);
output_file.close();
```

I am getting

> org.apache.poi.POIXMLException:
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package
>   should contain a content type part [M1.13]

Comment: As per my knowledge, HSSF target was BIFF8 file format which was much older version and not supporting Tab coloring. The tab color feature was added in later version. I am afraid its not possible with HSSF to change tab color. However, I cannot say I am 100% correct... Wait for others to answer it... I will be glad if we found some solution.

Comment: @Sankumarsingh, Thanks for the reply. Yes it is right. I just want to no is there is any way to do this. So that i have not to change my complete code.

Comment: as per my research it is not possible to change sheet tab color in HSSF sheets, but possible for XSSF sheets. this page might give you some insights:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093777/how-to-change-the-tab-color-of-a-worksheet-with-apache-poi

Comment: @NAK, Thanks for comment. Yes i have worked on SSSF. But here i want to update HSSF sheet by XSSF.