# How to get the tabs color in excel using java?

Tags: java

I searched a lot but could not get solution to it.Is there any way to get the tabs colour in excel using java.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7TcD.png)

In the image u will find three tabs sheet1,sheet2,sheet3 in excel i want to get the color of three tabs using java.

Comment: What libraries are you using?

Comment: Please explain in more details what you are doing / trying to do. Right now your question is too broad to give help.

Comment: I am using xssf and required libraries and Apache poi.I am trying to get the tabs colour in excel workbook based on the tab color I have to extract the data and copy in other sheet but am not able to get the tabs colour in excel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change the tab color of a worksheet with Apache Poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093777/how-to-change-the-tab-color-of-a-worksheet-with-apache-poi)

Comment: No it is not duplicate here i want to get the tab colour in the above mentioned link they are setting colour. I want to get the tab color here @ Atul Sharma

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `apache POI` library.

You can use

`HSSFColor.getIndexHash().get(myCell.getCellStyle().getFillBackgroundColor())`

to get the color infomations of the cell.

[Deatils of the apache POI getFillBackgroundColor methd](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCellStyle.html#getFillBackgroundColor%28%29)

[For more informations see stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615628/apche-poi-get-cell-color-when-reading-xlsx-file) maybe it is helpfull.

Comment: I am not asking about cell.i am trying to get the tabs colour which are present in workbook